# Proximity Alert Sample Code

Tags: android, maps, proximity

How to use the proximity alert to notify user when they are close to their destinations?

Can someone please give me a link with sample code, since Ive never worked with an app like this.

I need a solution asap

Thanks in advance

Comment: [try this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-proximity-alerts-tutorial.html)

Comment: It does not work. I get an error stating Activity has leaked the IntentReceiver that was originally registered.